# Not able to run a service on tomcat via IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea, run-configuration

I am working on a framework "beadledom".
I am also relatively very new to IntelliJ Idea, I have used eclipse before, the beadledom framework contains the project sub-module,
api
service
client
In Eclipse if we want to run the services, I would right click on "service" sub-module Run on Server -> tomcat ; and it would run.
My webapp is stored in "service" folder.

I have no clue how do I do it on IntelliJ

I did set the Run Configuartion.
I am being asked to create a "artifact" in Edit Configuration>Tomcat
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXG1o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html#artifact_def) is an archive, built from your project sources which constitutes your application. For Java EE web projects it is usually a war achrive which you deploy to an application server (e.g. Tomcat). In case of a Maven-based poject IntelliJ IDEA automatically creates web artifact, based on Maven pom.xml configuration which then you can select [to deploy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-a-java-ee-application.html#d132903e616) in [Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html) **Deployment** tab.

You could check [Developing a Java EE Application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-a-java-ee-application.html) tutorial for the general workflows in JavaEE-based projects in IntelliJ IDEA.